# Import can't recognize exported name when it is re-exported

Tags: javascript

I have the files `main.js`, `a.js` and `b.js`:

**main.js**

```js
import { foo } from './a'

console.log(foo)
```

**a.js**

```js
import objWithFoo from './b'

const bar = 24

export default { ...objWithFoo, bar }
```

**b.js**

```js
const foo = 42

export default { foo }
```

When I ran `main.js` using `node -r esm main.js` it gave me this error:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'file:///app/a.js' does not provide an export named 'foo'

**Question:**

Why is it loosing the named export?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using named exports - you are default exporting an object with properties.

```
import stuff from './a';

const { foo } = stuff;
...
```

If you wanted to use named exports:

```
import objWithFoo from './b'

const foo = { objWithFoo }
export { foo } // <- named export

const bar = 24
export default { bar } // <- object with properties
```